# Woocommerce checkout trigger validation after apply coupon programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I'm facing an issue with the Woocommerce checkout process where the validation is triggered and marks the address fields as invalid after applying a coupon programmatically. Here's the scenario:

During the checkout process, I have custom PHP code that applies coupons based on the chosen payment method using the woocommerce_after_calculate_totals action hook.

The coupon application works fine, and the discounts are correctly applied to the cart. However, after applying the coupon, the checkout address fields are marked as invalid

The issue seems to be related to the coupon application triggering the address validation process again, causing the fields to be marked as invalid. I would like to prevent this revalidation from occurring after applying the coupon programmatically.

```
function apply_coupon_based_on_payment_method($cart) {
    $selected_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    $args = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_coupon',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => [
            [
                'key' => 'allow_specific_payment_methods',
                'value' => 'yes',
                'compare' => '='
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $coupons = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($coupons as $coupon_post) {
        $coupon = new WC_Coupon($coupon_post->ID);
        $coupon_payment_methods = get_post_meta($coupon_post->ID, '_wjecf_payment_methods', true);

        $allow_specific_payment_methods = get_post_meta($coupon_post->ID, 'allow_specific_payment_methods', true);

        if ($allow_specific_payment_methods === 'yes') {
            if (is_array($coupon_payment_methods) && in_array($selected_payment_method, $coupon_payment_methods)) {
                if (!WC()->cart->has_discount($coupon->get_code())) {
                    WC()->cart->apply_coupon($coupon->get_code());
                }
            } else {
                if (WC()->cart->has_discount($coupon->get_code())) {
                    WC()->cart->remove_coupon($coupon->get_code());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $cart;
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_calculate_totals', 'apply_coupon_based_on_payment_method');
```

I have tried the following solutions, but none of them have resolved the problem:

Temporarily disabling the WooCommerce address validation using the woocommerce_validate_checkout_address filter within the coupon application code.

Modifying the coupon application code to run at different stages of the checkout process, such as the woocommerce_after_calculate_totals or woocommerce_checkout_process actions, but the issue persists.

I'm looking for guidance or alternative approaches to prevent the checkout address fields from being marked as invalid after applying the coupon programmatically. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This issue seems to be related to some other 3rd party plugins and/or some custom code linked to WooCommerce coupons. The code seems to have some heavy process, that could be avoided. For example, the custom field `_wjecf_payment_methods`should be included in your initial query in the meta query part, instead of using a `foreach` loop. If you want to be helped, you need to provide a **testable complete** code sample, that can allow us reproducing the problem. Also if the customer change of payment method, as payment methods changes don't trigger ajax checkout update, your code will fail.